# How can I properly use Dynamic MultiMonitor in xrandr?

Tags: 12.04, xrandr

I have a Dell Latitude E6520 with Ubuntu 12.04 and a Dell U2711 Monitor connected with my docking station.

I tried this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicMultiMonitor

```
xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.3.5
Server reports RandR version 1.3

lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
NVIDIA Driver Version: 295.40
Operating System: Linux-x86
Server Version Number: 11.0
NV-CONTROL-Version 1.27
```

I saved both configurations with (docked and mobile) using autorandr --save xxxx
I set up a Keyboard Shortcut do change the Screen on CTRL + F8.
But this only works when I switch from docked to mobile.

Calling autorandr --profile docked (Laptop is back in the docking station) doesn't change a thing.

```
autorandr --load docked
/usr/bin/xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
/usr/bin/xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Unable to fingerprint display configuration
 -> loading profile docked
/usr/bin/xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated.

Edit: The Configuration Layout is set on TwinView. And the Nvidia Settings only displays 1 Screen under X Server Information.